# Unable to install packages in R, getting the response 'the download source package are in ...'

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, r-package, install.packages

Please help!!!, this very R error is burning my head and productivity

I’ve encountered this error since I upgraded my Rstudio from 1.3.1093 to 2022.07.2
Whenever I try to install packages, it flags this error
between, I use R version 4.0.3

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2pXnal\downloaded_packages’
```

[image: install.packages error]

thereby causing this error

```
Error in library("ggplot2") : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

whenever I try to load the package.

But I noticed:

- It does not do this to all packages but the heavy and important packages like ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, sf,...
- It basically downloads the package to this weird folder **C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2pXnal\downloaded_packages** instead of **C:\Users\USER\Documents\R\win-library\4.0** and refuses to unzip the package file
- due to multiple trial and error, I have lots of the wierd files beginning with *rtmp...*
  [image: rtmp... files]

Amongst other things, I've tried:

- Downgrading back to the version of Rstudio I was usng before the error i.e back to 1.3.1093
- Changing my CRAN mirror
- Uninstalling and installing both R and Rstudiio
- Manually installing the packages from RStudio by navigating to packages  install
- Manually unzip and move the library folder to …, which I think is the right folder for it to work but still the same error.
- tried installing individually. instead of `install.packages(c(a,b,c,...,x,y,z))`, i used multiple `install.packages(x)`
- Tried the main cran mirror as below

```
install.packages('ggplot2', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

I was expecting the `install.packages()` and `library()` functons to run smoothly

Amongst other things, I've tried:

- Downgrading back to the version of Rstudio I was using before the error i.e back to 1.3.1093
- Changing my CRAN mirror
- Uninstalling and installing both R and Rstudiio
- Manually installing the packages from RStudio by navigating to packages  install
- Manually unzip and move the library folder to …, which I think is the right folder for it to work but still the same error.
- tried installing individually. instead of `install.packages(c(a,b,c,...,x,y,z))`, i used multiple `install.packages(x)`

Comment: Don't care about the `Rtmp2pXnal` folders, you can think of them as temp files from where packages get automatically installed. You should use R 4.2.2, your Version (4.0.3) is outdated. Please then try `install.packages('ggplot2')` and add the entire console output as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74501134/edit) to your question, you might have missed something important. Please also add your windows version. You can also tray a [daily](https://dailies.rstudio.com/) which sometimes helps.

Comment: Does this happen when running R-gui or R from the command line?  if not, then it's a problem with Rstudio and you should contact them directluy

Comment: looks like you missing some dependencies. "The downloaded source packages are in.." is the last error, scroll up check where the first error occurs, something like : ' "xy" not available , not found.'. then install this dependencies. try install.packages("ggplot2") again. see if more dependencies are needed..